# Can I import and use Vue component inside Vue native component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

I am new in Vue native also I encountered a question which is, `can I use the Vue component inside a Vue native component such as Vue-chart and etc.....`

Comment: Have you tried…?

Comment: Not now, that why I am just in R&D to choose Vue native or not.

Comment: Maybe do a little R&D to see if using the component in a Vue native component works then? You’d get the answer much quicker if you just tried instead of creating a Stack Overflow question where someone else would have to try it and give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every component you should use working with vue native should be react native components.... Just install the react native component, import it and rewrite the usage the vue way and it is going to work....you don't have to use vue components since vue native is just a wrapper around react native. Working with vue native, what you are actually working with is react native...so everything you can do with react native, you can do using vue native. If you want to use chart, look for react native chart component and use that instead.